# android application development app error

Tags: java, android

Whenever I try to run the android application through emulator I get such errors and I can't find the app on emulator, please if anyone could help me.

```
[2014-01-02 18:54:42 - Mouse] Failed to install Mouse.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-01-02 18:54:42 - Mouse] (null)
[2014-01-02 18:54:43 - Mouse] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 0):

Emulator 5554 issues can be due to multiple reasons. You can check by:

1) increasing the ADB timeout. If you are using Eclipse this can be done by
Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB Connection Timeout (ms) (I use 15000)

2) Reboot your phone or use command 
`adb kill-server 
adb start-server`.

3) Finally restart the emulator and try doing connection once again using new usb cable.

These are just options and not any specific reason that it shall work or not.